# "Unused CSS selector" when using a SASS themify mixin with Svelte and Vite:

Tags: sass, themes, svelte, vite, mixins

I'm trying to create a small web application using Svelte.
One of the requirements is to be able to change the application "theme" on demand, for example - dark theme, light theme, high contrast, and so on.

I've been using an online mixin snippet to help me with that -
https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1

However, this doesn't work consistently, and I often get errors like:
`[vite-plugin-svelte] /path/to/svelte/component.svelte:61:0 Unused CSS selector "main.default-theme div.some.element.identification"`
even tho the selector **is used** and is receiving it's non-themed attributes.

Inside a `themes.scss` file:

```
@mixin themify($themes) {

    @each $theme,
    $map in $themes {
        main.#{$theme}-theme & {
            $theme-map: () !global;

            @each $key,
            $submap in $map {
                $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
                $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
            }

            @content;
            $theme-map: null !global;
        }
    }
}

@function themed($key) {
    @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}

$themes: (
    default: (
        strokeColor: green,
        fillColor: red,
    ),
);
```

and inside another scss file that is importing `themes.scss`:

```
div.some.element.identification {
    some-non-themed-attribute: some-value;

    @include themify($themes) {
        stroke: themed('strokeColor');
        fill: themed('fillColor');
    }
}
```

now the punchline - when using this methodology, *some* elements are receiving their appropriate themed attributes, and others **dont**.
I am also seeing the following error:
`[vite-plugin-svelte] /path/to/svelte/component.svelte:61:0 Unused CSS selector "main.default-theme div.some.element.identification"`

the issue doesn't seem to be in the css selectors - since the elements that **dont** receive the themed attributes, **still receive** the other non-themed attributes in the same css clause.

Two final observations -

1. When I'm building the project (using vite build), I can see that the css asset file being created doesn't include the css selectors that are missing their themed attributes.
2. When i'm using the devtools to locate the supposedly unused selectors (whose themed attributes are not present), they can be found - despite the error message.

I've been trying different way to solve this issue and nothing works consistently.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try checking these different items:

- If you use svelte-preprocess, try to add `` scss: { prependData: `@import 'src/styles/theme.scss';` } `` or whatever the path to your theme is, to the config object.
- If it still does not work, maybe try to swap svelte-preprocess with vite-preprocess
- Disable any potential css purge plugin

Comment: So I dont know why but importing the scss file inside the <script> tag of a component
(aka `import './myComponent.scss';` instead of inside the src attribute of a style tag solves this issue - but i'll try your approach too.

Would you happen to know **why** this is?

Comment: No I don't but it does look like a static asset parsing failure. When I used scss, I frequently ran into those kind of issues and ```prependData``` helped the bundler to find the "entry point" of my scss mess and everything went back in order

Comment: If you use JS `import` it invoked Vite to pull it in.